# Как передать несколько параметров из powershell

Tags: zabbix

У меня есть скрипт powershell на машине windows, который просто выводит значение переменной write-host 10. Простая строчка.
Для этого в агенте заббикса я прописываю:
UserParameter=fileserv.folder1[*],powershell.exe -nologo C:\scripts\CheckDFS.ps1 $1

А как мне снять второе значение, если я в скрипте напишу дополнительно write-host 20
Что нужно дописать в агенте заббикса и как правильно написать в скрипте powershell? Спасибо.

Comment: никто тут не отвечает. забили. то ли дело в других разделах..

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт который выполняется через UserParameter должен возвращать одно значение. Если ваш скрипт возвращает несколько значений, то в качестве обходного решения используйте вызов zabbix_sender внутри скрипта, а сам скрипт должен возвращать 0 если завершился без ошибок.

На zabbix сервере сделайте дополнительный элемент данных типа zabbix trapper и принимайте туда результаты работы скрипта.